# Use jQuery resizable to change padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use jQuery Resizable to essentially edit the padding on an element and have been struggling to get this bad boy to work or to find resources that might give some insight.

I am essentially doing this to map the height change to padding change:

```
$(".block-wrapper").resizable({
      handles: "n, s",
      resize: function(event, ui) {

          var padding = ((ui.size.height - ui.originalSize.height)/2);

          ui.element.css({
              'height': 'initial',
              'padding-top': padding+'px',
              'padding-bottom': padding+'px'
          });

       }

});
```

(more here: https://jsfiddle.net/6vs37ot0/1/)

And it works perfectly the first time BUT when you go back to adjust it again, it snaps back to the original size before resizing again.

Any ideas on how I might be able to solve this would be AWESOME.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the line `var padding = ((ui.size.height - ui.originalSize.height)/2);`

When you stop resizing the block, i.e. on `mouseup`,  `ui.originalSize.height` is set to the last `ui.size.height`, so `ui.size.height - ui.originalSize.height` is back to zero and your padding is gone !

But why do you go through all the trouble of using padding ?
If it's just to **center vertically** the text, there is some simpler **css** solution.

```
.block-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
 }
```

and the simpler js :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(".block-wrapper").resizable({handles: "n, s"});
});
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. The padding is applied just fine, on mouseup included. It's when you go to resize it again, it clears the padding as if the block were starting from its original size. My guess is that resizable is reading the current height (which doesnt include the padding, obviously) causing it to snap back to size on subsequent resizes.

Comment: @JeremyAbraham: Yes I agree, the padding is applied just fine. What I meant is that the padding value, calculated using `ui.size.height` and `ui.originalSize.height` with always be zero when you start to resize, because `originalSize` is not the first size of the block before any resize, it's rather the size just before you move the mouse after clicking to drag. And what about my second option ? Do you really need to adjust the padding ?